# How to expose multiple port using a load balancer services in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, port, load-balancing

I have created a cluster using the google cloud platform (container engine) and deployed a pod using the following YAML file:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: deployment-name
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: pod-name
      labels: 
        app: app-label
    spec:
      containers: 
      - name: container-name
      image: gcr.io/project-id/image-name
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
      ports:
      - name: port80
        containerPort: 80
      - name: port443
        containerPort: 443
      - name: port6001
        containerPort: 6001
```

Then I want to create a service that enables the pod to listen on all these ports. I know that the following YAML file works to create a service that listens on one port:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: service-name
spec:    
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector: 
    app: app-label
  type: LoadBalancer
```

However when I want the pod to listen on multiple ports like this, it doesn't work:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: service-name
spec:    
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  - port: 6001
    targetPort: 6001
  selector: 
    app: app-label
  type: LoadBalancer
```

How can I make my pod listen to multiple ports?

Comment: Have you tried with multiple services?

Comment: @danielepolencic thank you for answering.
I have tried with multiple services and it works, the issue with doing that is that you get one external IP address per service. 
Is there no way to enable pods to listen to multiple ports without having multiple services or to have a service that listens on multiple ports?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You could have multiple services, one for each port. As you pointed out, each service will end up with a different IP address
2. You could have a single service with multiple ports. In this particular case, you must give all ports a name.

In your case, the service becomes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-name
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  - name: something
    port: 6001
    targetPort: 6001
  selector:
    app: app-label
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This is necessary so that endpoints can be disambiguated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you also know how to expose a range of ports (eg. from 6001-6300)? @danielepolencic

Comment: From what I could understand, k8s doesn't support port ranges as of now: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23864

Comment: Hi, I tried this way and I am not able to access the IP and port from internet. If I expose one port its working fine. But when i expose 80 and 443 like above. It fails. Page is not opened. Does it work for you?

Comment: can i do that with 2 diferents pods?

Comment: Update: there's a workaround https://github.com/kelseyhightower/dynamic-ports-tutorial