# Kubernetes: Expose multiple services internally & externally

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Am using AKS for my cluster

**Scenario**:
We have multiple API's (say svc1, svc2 & svc3 accessible on port 101, 102, 103).
These API links need to be exposed to client and are also used internally in application.

**Question**:
I want to expose this to both external & internal load balancer on same ports.
Also when i access the service internally, i want them to be accessible by service name (Example: svc1:101)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I was able to fix the issue without using NodePort/ClusterIP.

Solution is pretty simple but seems its not documented.

Only thing we have to do is have multiple tags where 1 tag is same as of external load balancer and other tag you have same matching service.

This will map your replicaset to both service & external loadbalancer.

Detailed answer available on - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/exposing-multiple-portsservices-same-load-balancer-sunil-agarwal

Comment: Great article that you posted. Saved my day. Reduced from 4 public ips to 1

Answer (score 1):

In Kubernetes:

- if you want to expose something **internally only**, you should use **ClusterIP** service type
- if you want to expose both internally & externally, use **LoadBalancer** (or **NodePort**) service type.

Please check [Kubernetes: Service Types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) for more details.

Comment: I know this. My requirement is i want both

Comment: if i use node port, for each service i will get different public IP. I want one common IP for all services (port will be different). At the same time, I want all services to be accessible internally.