# Loadbalancer that serves traffic inbound on one port to multiple Pod ports

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, amazon-eks

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to have a client connect to a loadbalancer on a specific port, and then have the lb loadbalance traffic across multiple ports of the same pod.

Something like this:

Client ---> lb-ip:8080 ---> Pod:8080 & Pod:8081

I'm currently using EKS's network load balancer.

Comment: I think that is not possible, why don't you want to consider using multiple ports ?  See example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147664/how-to-expose-multiple-port-using-a-load-balancer-services-in-kubernetes

Comment: i have my reasonings behind this choice and i feel like it would take a while to explain everything. Unfortunately I cannot use multiple ports without changing logic in our application. Thank you for the advice though